# Performance socket nodejs + mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, performance

I am developing an application that consist of a server in node.js, basically a socket that is listening for incoming connections.

Data that arrive to my server, come from GPS trackers (30 approximately), that send 5 records per minute each one, so in a minute a will have `5*30 = 150` records, in a hour i will have `150*60 = 9000` records, in a day `9000*24 =216000` and in a month `216000*30 = 6.480.000` million of records.

In addition to the latitude and longitude, i have to store in the database (MySql) the cumulative distance of each tracker. Each tracker send to server positions, and i have to calculate kms between 2 points every time i receive data (to decrease the work to the database when it has millions of records).

So the question is, **what is the correct way to sum the kilometers and store it?**

I think sum the entire database is not a solution because in millions of records will be very slow. Maybe, every time i have to store a new point (150 times per minute), **can I do a select last record in database and then sum the cumulative kilometer with the new distance calc?**

Comment: You could use an in memory datastore such as [Redis](http://redis.io) to store the cumulative distance. It's a key -> value store so you could use the tracker ID for the key, then use the add method to add the new distance to the running total.

Comment: Agreed @DanielWaghorn we use a combination of Redis and MongoDB at work and are dealing with 500k records per day.  Redis is a great solution for holding key/value data that would otherwise be expensive on a db query.  In your case you would compute the distance between points every minute and then store that sum as the new value for that specific key in your redis store.  Redis is atomic and synchronises any writes to it, sounds like an ideal use case for your project.  We also set up a cron job that periodically writes the value out to disk in case the redis store crashes (not happened yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2.5 inserts per second is only a modest rate.  6M records/month -- no problem.

How do you compute the KMs?  Compute the distance of the previous GPS reading to the current?  Or maybe back to the start?  Keep in mind that GPS readings can be a bit flaky; a car going in a straight line may look drunk when plotted every 12 seconds.  Meanwhile, I will assume you need some kind of index on (sensor, sequence) to keep track of the previous (or first) reading to do the distance.

But, what will you do with the distance?  Is it being continually read out for display somewhere?  That is, are you updating some non-MySQL thingie 150 times per minute?  If so, you have an app that should receive the new GPS reading, store it into MySQL, read the starting point (or remember it), compute the kms and update the graph.  That is, MySQL is not the focus here, but your app is.

As for representation of lat/lng, I reference [*my cheat sheet*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices) to see that `FLOAT` may be optimal.

Kilometers should almost certainly be stored as `FLOAT`.  That gives you about 7 significant digits of precision.  You should decide whether to the value represents "meters" or "kilometers".  (The precision is the same.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made some test with 20 M records in my database and queries take only 0.0003 seg. I calculate KMs between new point and prior. I only need the kms for a backend operations, not to show in a visual map. Somethings i have problems when tracker is stopped. For example tracker is stopped 90 seconds, but y recive a lot of diferents lat/lng with a big margin of error (sometimes i register 20 - 30 kms when tracker is not moving). So i`am trying to do some code that discard positions when speed is near to 0 km/h. What do you think about that?

Comment: On a hike, my phone clocks 0.5km while I am sitting still eating lunch.  I think the trick is to question sudden runs, such as 100km/hr from one reading to the next -- one or both location is wrong and/or something else.  And/or some smoothing algorithm.  I don't know the physics -- is an occasional reading "bad", or are all readings "off"?  (In my experience, it is mostly the latter.